# Cannot find monodevelop on PC

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I have downloaded MonoDevelop from their website at https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/ and have installed it and the GTK. However, after the installation, I cannot find the IDE anywhere. Using the search function on my computer, I have tried finding it under "mono", "monodevelop", "xamarin", "GTK", but to no avail.

I have tried launching the installer again and repairing the installation, but it still does not work. There was no shortcut created on my desktop and it had no choice for opening it directly after the installation.

I am afraid that I may have unintentionally installed a virus due to this issue.

Please help. Thank you very much!

Comment: @User wouldn't that mean that installing *any* implementation of the .NET framework would not allow you to write an application that starts?  I'm thinking that's not true?

Comment: @User I don't understand what you meant there... I know that the .net framework isn't an app to start but I'm talking about the IDE... unless I did not install that but then that is what I specifically looked for.

Comment: Wait but that is exactly where I installed it... It does make any sense. Like I understand what you mean now but that is what I did.

Comment: @User Ok here is exactly what I did: I go on to the monodevelop website. this one to be exact <https://www.monodevelop.com/> and then I scroll down and click on the "Download" button, right before Feature Highlights and then it leads me to the download page. then I click on "download GTK"

Comment: What is the operating system?

Comment: @LexLi Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [download page](https://www.monodevelop.com/download/#fndtn-download-win) clearly says,

> **MonoDevelop for Windows is available from source only** Please refer to the [building guide](https://www.monodevelop.com/developers/building-monodevelop/) for more information about how to install and
>   configure your MonoDevelop.

So you have to build it from the source code, or use binaries built by others (mine can be found from [here](https://github.com/lextm/monodevelop-windows)). (**Update: I added an MSI installer https://github.com/lextm/monodevelop-windows/issues/1**)

BTW, most people should use VS Community edition or VSCode. MonoDevelop on Windows does not give you much more value.

Answer (score 1):

You reach the wrong site.

mono != monodevelop

Monodevelop it here: https://www.monodevelop.com/